# How to display n number of rows per page from search results

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter, pagination

I want to display 7 results on every page using pagination but I'm only getting it on first page 7 and then when i click next page it does not display any result.

**Controller**

```
 function display($offset=0)
 {
   $limit=7;     
   $select = $this->input->post('select');
   $name = $this->input->post('name'); 

   if($select=='none')
    {
     echo '<script>alert("please Select college");</script>';
   $this->load->library('user_agent');
   $page_url=$this->agent->referrer();
   redirect($page_url,'refresh');
   }
   else
   {



     $result['numOfRows']=$this->getmodel2->countRows();
     $this->load->library('pagination'); #2
     $this->load->library('table');
     $config=array(
    'base_url'=> site_url('Verify3/display/?name='.$name),
    'total_rows'=> $result['numOfRows'][0]['count'],
    'per_page'=>$limit,
    'page_query_string' => TRUE,
    'num_links'=>2
     );        
     $result['j']=$this->getmodel2->getSearchbook($limit,$offset,$name,$select);           #3
$this->pagination->initialize($config);     #4
$result['pagination']=$this->pagination->create_links();  #5
$this->load->view('imageview3',$result);
}
}
```

**Model**

```
function getSearchBook($limit,$offset,$name,$select) {


 $query="Select * from home where ownerid='$name' and select='$select limit $limit offset $offset";

 $result_query= $this->db->query($query);
 }
```

Comment: any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a session to store your input data and send session data in the query.

```
if ($name!=NULL&&$select!=NULL) {
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('search_data');
    $session_data['search'] = $name;
    $session_data['search'] = $select;
   $this->session->set_userdata('search_data', $session_data);
   }
  $result['j']=$this->getmodel2->getSearchbook($limit,$offset,$this->session->userdata['search_data']['search'],$this->session->userdata['search_data']['select']);
```